# How to access controls of a specific row in a table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dom

I have a table to which I am appending rows dynamically on button click at clientside. Please take a look..

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/7/)

As you can see I have a button in each row. I want to access the controls of the row whose button has been clicked. How can I get the corresponding row number on button click and use that row number to access other controls in that row?

**MarkUp:**

```
<table id="field">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="row1" class="row">
        <td> <span class='num'>1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></select></td><td>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteField">Delete Field</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
             filldd();
             CreateDP();
            var rowstring = "<tr class='row'><td class='number'></td><td><input type='text'/></td><td><select class='myDropDownLisTId'/><input type='text' class='datepicker'/></td><td><input type='submit'></input></td></tr>";
             $("#addField").click(function (event) {
             $("#field tbody").append(rowstring);
             filldd();
             CreateDP();

             if ($("td").hasClass("number")) {
                 var i = parseInt($(".num:last").text()) + 1;
                 $('.row').last().attr("id", "row"+i);
                 $($("<span class='num'> " + i + " </span>")).appendTo($(".number")).closest("td").removeClass('number');
             }
             event.preventDefault();
         });

         $("#deleteField").click(function (event) {
             var lengthRow = $("#field tbody tr").length;
             if (lengthRow > 1)
                 $("#field tbody tr:last").remove();
             event.preventDefault();
         });

});

 function filldd(){
    var data = [
    { id: '0', name: 'test 0' },
    { id: '1', name: 'test 1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'test 2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'test 3' },
    { id: '4', name: 'test 4' },
];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $(".myDropDownLisTId").last().append(
            $('<option />', {
                'value': data[i].id,
                'name': data[i].name,
                'text': data[i].name
            })
         );
     }
         }

         function CreateDP(){
             $(".datepicker").last().datepicker();
         }
```

Comment: In which event you want to access controls. Also Post your relevent code here at SO. JSFiddle is not a substitution

Comment: I want to access controls when I click on button. I want to access that particular row and its row number whose button has just been clicked.

Comment: @Satpal there is a submit button in each row.

Comment: Might http://jsfiddle.net/XD8rG/ help you, In example I have just alerted input value you can work forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to access them on submit click.To get index(row number 0 index based) of clicked elements closest tr:

```
$(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex;
```

or

```
$(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex
```

And to access the elements within same tr you can use:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('selector here'); //example:$(this).closest('tr').find('.myDropDownLisTId').val()
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/8/)**

Comment: Marking answer in 3...2..1! Marked.
Thank bro! :)

Comment: You are right.. the problem is with something else .. please take a look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23108282/2064292