# window.onload not working in IE8

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am opening a child pop up window and calling a parent function from child window. But I am not able to do so on IE8. The problem I believe is with `childwindow.onload` are there any alternatives?

**Parent**

```
function CallPopUp(rowindex,controlname ) {

            var childWindow = open('test1.aspx', '1397127848655', 'resizable=no,width=700,height=500');
            childWindow.onload = function () {

                var hidden1 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden1');
                var hidden2 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden2');
                alert('asdas');
                hidden1.innerHTML = rowindex;
                hidden2.innerHTML = controlname;
            }
        }
```

**Child**

```
<span id="hidden1"></span>
        <span id="hidden2"></span>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

           function updateParent(code, description) {

               var id = document.getElementById('hidden1').innerHTML;
               var controlname = document.getElementById('hidden2').innerHTML;
               window.opener.setValue(id,controlname,code,description);

               window.close();

               return false;

           }

           $(document).on('click', '.submit', function () {

               updateParent($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(), $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
               return false;
           })
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried without `onload`? Just `var childWindow = open(...); var hidden1 = ...`

Comment: @Teemu I did. And it works without onload on IE8 BUT then it stops working on chrome.

Comment: Do you see any error on Console of Developer Tool?

Comment: @TaditKumarDash Nope no error that I can see.

Comment: @TaditKumarDash as you can see I am trying to set value of span which is on child pop up from a function which is on parent pop up. I am able to do so in chrome but I am not able to do so in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semi-colon to the end of the `onload` function e.g:

```
function CallPopUp(rowindex,controlname ) {

        var childWindow = open('test1.aspx', '1397127848655', 'resizable=no,width=700,height=500');
        childWindow.onload = function () {

            var hidden1 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden1');
            var hidden2 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden2');
            alert('asdas');
            hidden1.innerHTML = rowindex;
            hidden2.innerHTML = controlname;
        };
    }
```

I had a similar problem in IE8 before and it was down to this.